# Setting parameters from a worksheet for an ODBC query in Excel

Tags: excel, odbc

In Excel (2021) Queries and Connections I have an onprem database connection (under Connections) and an ODBC Snowflake connection (under Queries). In both cases I'm using them to execute a procedure with parameters from a worksheet.

For the onprem connection I have the command defined as EXEC procedure <parameter1, parameter2,...>.

[image]

The parameters are then defined by the "Parameters" option below the command and each of them points to a value in a worksheet (for example B1) like this:

[image]

What I want to know is how I can do the same thing for the ODBC query, where I don't have such an option to input parameters.

Here is how my connection is defined with fixed values:

[image]

How can I make the fixed values above to be parameters from a worksheet (for example A1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by defining the parameters in Name Manager and using PowerQuery advanced editor with the following code:

```
let
    PARAMETER1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="PARAMETER1"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    PARAMETER2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="PARAMETER2"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    PARAMETER3 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="PARAMETER3"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    
    Source = Odbc.Query("dsn=Snowflake-connection", "CALL DATABASE.SCHEMA.pr_procedure('" & PARAMETER1 & "', '" & PARAMETER2 & "', '" & PARAMETER3 & "')")
in
    Source
```